# Calculating factorial on FORTRAN with integer variables. Memory overflow

Tags: memory, integer, fortran, overflow, factorial

I'm doing a program with FORTRAN that is a bit special. I can only use integer variables, and as you know with these you've got a memory overflow when you try to calculate a factorial superior to 12 or 13. So I made this program to avoid this problem:

http://lendricheolfiles.webs.com/codigo.txt

But something very strange is happening. The program calculates the factorial well 4 or 5 times and then gives a memory overflow message. I'm using Windows 8 and I fear it might be the cause of the failure, or if it's just that I've done something wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't get a _memory overflow_ when using a scalar `integer` variable but rather an _integer overflow_.

Comment: Yes, you're right sorry. I wanted to say that you get an integer overflow when you try to calculate a factorial superior to 13, but what I get is a memory overflow in my program. Here's the error: Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  6f6a5456
#1  6f69321f
#2  004011e9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

M.S.B.'s answer has the gist of your problem: your array indices go out of bounds at a couple of places.

In three loops, `cifra - 1 == 0` is out of bounds:

```
do cifra=ncifras,1,-1
  factor(1,cifra-1) = factor(1,cifra)/10    ! factor is (1:2, 1:ncifras)
  factor(1,cifra) = mod(factor(1,cifra),10)
enddo 
! :
! Same here:
do cifra=ncifras,1,-1
 factor(2,cifra-1) = factor(2,cifra)/10
 factor(2,cifra) = mod(factor(2,cifra),10)
enddo
!:
do cifra=ncifras,1,-1
  sumaprovisional(cifra-1) = sumaprovisional(cifra-1)+(sumaprovisional(cifra)/10)
  sumaprovisional(cifra) = mod(sumaprovisional(cifra),10)
enddo
```

In the next case, the value of `cifra - (fila - 1)` goes out of bounds:

```
do fila=1,nfilas
  do cifra=1,ncifras  
    ! Out of bounds for all cifra < fila:
    sumando(fila,cifra-(fila-1)) = factor(1,cifra)*factor(2,ncifras-(fila-1))
  enddo
  sumaprovisional = sumaprovisional+sumando(fila,:)
enddo
```

You should be fine if you rewrite the first three loops as `do cifra = ncifras, 2, -1` and the inner loop of the other case as `do cifra = fila, ncifras`. Also, in the example program you posted, you first have to allocate `resultado` properly before passing it to the subroutine.

Answer (score 2):

Try compiling with run-time subscript checking.   In Fortran segmentation faults are generally caused either by subscript errors or by mismatches between actual and dummy arguments (i.e., between arguments in the call to a procedure and the arguments as declared in the procedure).  I'll make a wild guess from glancing at your code that you have have a subscript error -- let the compiler find it for you by turning on run-time subscript checking.  Most Fortran compilers have this as an compilation option.

P.S.  You can also do calculations like this by using already written packages, e.g., the arbitrary precision arithmetic software of David Bailey, et al., available in Fortran 90 at http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~dhbailey/mpdist/